# javamail and gmail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

1. The following code throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. Any idea why?

   ```
    Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
    folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");

    int totalMessages = folder.getMessageCount();
    //totalMessages is 17000

     folder.getMessages(16900, 16999)   --- here I am trying to get the NEWEST 99                                                                                         messages.
   ```

This code throws the exception indexoutofbounds even though there are so many mails. What am I doing wrong?

1. folder.getMessages() - get all the emails from 1st email to last. In my case 17000!! How          do I get the emails starting from newest to oldest? 
   I only want to see the latest emails - around 100 of them. Is this possible?

Comment: I got it - the last email is folder.getMessageCount() - folder.getDeletedMessageCount();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never us magic values in code, it will just cause you pain. Try:

```
int messagesToDisplay = 100;
folder.getMessages(totalMessages  - messagesToDisplay , totalMessages);
```

From the [JavaDoc](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Folder.html#getMessages%28int,%20int%29) the messages are identified with a 1 based array not 0.

Can you also add the stack trace please.

Comment: Same error . I tried this first and when I got the error, substituted the actual values and made the Api call again.

Comment: And the stack trace isjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkRange(IMAPFolder.java:361)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessage(IMAPFolder.java:1251)
 at javax.mail.Folder.getMessages(Folder.java:866)
 at ashwin.GMailReader.readMail(GMailReader.java:38)
 at ashwin.GMailReader.main(GMailReader.java:56)

Comment: Does getting a single message using `folder.getMessage(1)` work ?

Comment: folder.getMessage(messageNumber) works for smaller numbers.  Looks like the total count retrieves count of deleted and archived messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

please open the folder in read or read_write mode first.

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```